# Access distributed cache from MrJob

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am writing hadoop app using  MrJob. I need to use distributed cache to access to some files. 
I know that there is an option -files in hadoop streaming but don't know how to access it in the program.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think You have to use

**mrjob.compat.supports_new_distributed_cache_options(version)**

And then use  -files and -archives instead of -cacheFile and -cacheArchive

May be you will get more [here](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/utils-compat.html?highlight=distributed%20cache#mrjob.compat.supports_new_distributed_cache_options)

Answer (score -1):

You shall read files in your program as though the files are available there itself, i.e. the file is local in the same directory as the running code.

I am not good in python, hence here is the example in ruby, `mapper.rb`:

```
begin
    file = File.open("my-distributed-cache-file.txt")
    while (line = file.gets)
            # do something with your file
    end
    file.close
end
# Rest of mapper code
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I try to use --hadoop-arg in MrJob to pass the cache file, i.e.,  --hadoop-arg -files hdfs://localhost:54310/cache.txt but it's not working.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which specifically asks for mrjob, the Python package.